# Java BlackJack not entering while loop

Tags: java

First of all, I apologize because this code seems inefficient to me, but my professor wants it this way (the comments are hers). I have many problems here, but a central one seems to be that when I run the program it does not enter the for loop. Therefore I'm assuming it is not entering the while loop that the for loop is in, and I'm not sure why. Here is the "modified" blackjack program, any help is appreciated:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class BlackJack {
enum Decisions

{
    HIT, STAND, SURRENDER, QUIT, PLAY, NOTVALID;
    // NOTVALID is used to re-ask to play again
}

enum Card {
    ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, QUEEN, JACK, KING;
}

// Tells you if the Decision enum is valid or not
public static boolean containsDecision(String decision) {
    for (Decisions d : Decisions.values()) {
        if (d.name().equals(decision)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Tells you what is the integer value of said Card enum
public static int getCardValue(int pick) {
    if (pick == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (pick >= 10 && pick <= 12) {
        return 10;
    }
    return pick + 1;
}

// 1 pts
public static int housePlay(int houseCardSum) {
    int cardPick;

    cardPick = -1;

    while (houseCardSum <= 17)
    {
        getCardValue(cardPick); 
        houseCardSum = (cardPick + houseCardSum);

        System.out.println("Hit from house! CARD: " + cardPick + " VALUE: " + houseCardSum);
    }   
    return houseCardSum;
}

// 1.5 pts
public static void findWinner(int playerCardSum, int houseCardSum, Decisions decision) {

        houseCardSum = housePlay(houseCardSum);

        if ( (playerCardSum > 21) || (houseCardSum > 21))
    {
        if (houseCardSum > 21) 
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry you lose!");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("You win!");
        }
    }
    else if (decision == Decisions.SURRENDER)
    {
        System.out.println("You lose because you surrendered!");
    }
    else if (playerCardSum == houseCardSum)
    {
        System.out.println("Its a push (tie)!");
    }
    else if ((playerCardSum > houseCardSum) && (playerCardSum < 21))
    {
        System.out.println("You win!");
    }
    else if ( (playerCardSum == 21) && (houseCardSum != 21) )
    {
        System.out.println("Blackjack win!");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry you lose!");
    }
    // if, else if, else, check playerCardSum, houseCardSum as well as if
    // Decision equaled to SURRENDER
    // print the House and You Hand at the end
    // call housePlay function and assign the output to houseCard function
    // iff not playerCardSum is not 21 and Decisions is not Surrender
    // these below will be used moved them around freely in this function
    // where you need too.
     // put in correct branch sub
                                            // statement
    System.out.println("House Hand: " + houseCardSum + " Your Hand: " + playerCardSum); // this
                                                                                        // is
                                                                                        // printed
                                                                                        // out
                                                                                        // after
                                                                                        // all
                                                                                        // branch
                                                                                        // statements
                                                                                        // assessed
}

// 7.5pts
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("========== BlackJack ==========");
    System.out.print("What is your name: ");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String playerName;

    playerName = keyboard.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Okay, " + playerName + ", let's play!");

    Decisions decision = Decisions.PLAY ;

    int cardPick;

    cardPick = -1;

    while ( decision != Decisions.QUIT);
    {
        int playerSum;
        int houseSum;

        playerSum = 0;
        houseSum = 0;

        Card holeCard = null;


        for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {

                Random newCard = new Random();

                cardPick = newCard.nextInt(14);


                playerSum = playerSum + getCardValue(cardPick);

                System.out.println("Card: " + (Card.values()[cardPick]) );  

                System.out.println("Sum of your hand: " + playerSum );              
            }
        }
```

Comment: @flkes the indentation is fine, what are you talking about?

Comment: Semicolon dude. `while (decision != Decisions.Quit);` Remove the `;`

Comment: A loop (while or otherwise) is followed by either a code block (surrounded by { } ) or a single statement.  The semicolon is considered to be a valid "do nothing" statement and so you continually loop the same condition without running any code on each loop.

Comment: This question is basically a typo. Please close as off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semicolon after the while statement.

```
while ( decision != Decisions.QUIT);

while ( decision != Decisions.QUIT)
```

Comment: This is more of a "close as typographical error" kind of question